# DialogFlow StreamingDetectIntentResponse doesn't return ResponseId, QueryText, Transcript or anything except LanguageCode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dialogflow-es, grpc

I have successfully used Grpc in Unity and sent request to Dialog flow and received response. You can check the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53773981/10789116)

However the whole returned result is the following only

> { "queryResult": { "languageCode": "ja" } }

The expected response id, query text, etc are not returned.
When testing in console.dialogflow.com I get the following result

> {
>     "responseId": "cdf8003e-6599-4a28-9314-f4462c36e21b",
>     "queryResult": {
>       "queryText": "おはようございます",
>       "speechRecognitionConfidence": 0.92638445,
>       "languageCode": "ja"
>     }
>   }

However when I tried in console.dialogflow.com and didn't say anything I got

> { "queryResult": { "languageCode": "ja" } }

So perhaps the InputAudio encoding is wrong somehow.

Here's how I do it

```
var serializedByteArray = convertToBytes(samples);
request.InputAudio = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(serializedByteArray);
```

And convert to bytes is like the following

```
public static byte[] convertToBytes(float[] audio)
{
    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

    foreach (float audioI in audio) {
        bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(audioI));
    }

    return bytes.ToArray();
}
```

The audio source is define as follows where sampleRate is 16000

```
audioSource.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, 30, sampleRate);
```

I made sure to set sample rate hz properly.

```
queryInput.AudioConfig.SampleRateHertz = sampleRate;
```

### Edit:

I have logged the recorded bytes from unity to a file (have all the bytes streamed appended together) and have written a console application to test the binary generated but using DetectIntent rather than streaming detect intent.

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(privateKey);

var url = "dialogflow.googleapis.com";

Grpc.Core.Channel channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(url, credential.ToChannelCredentials());


var client = SessionsClient.Create(channel);


CallOptions options = new CallOptions();

DetectIntentRequest detectIntentRequest = new DetectIntentRequest();
detectIntentRequest.Session = "projects/projectid/agent/sessions/" + "detectIntent";
QueryInput queryInput = new QueryInput();
queryInput.AudioConfig = new InputAudioConfig();
queryInput.AudioConfig.LanguageCode = "ja";
queryInput.AudioConfig.SampleRateHertz = sampleRate;//must be between 8khz and 48khz
queryInput.AudioConfig.AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Linear16;

detectIntentRequest.QueryInput = queryInput;

detectIntentRequest.InputAudio = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\temp\\audio.bytes"));
 var response = client.DetectIntent(detectIntentRequest);
        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(response.ResponseId);
Console.Read();
```

I still get this (and empty response.ResponseId)

> { "queryResult": { "languageCode": "ja" } }

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Have you reproduced this in a console app as I've suggested? If so, the Unity aspect is irrelevant. Please show the code you're using - ideally as a complete console app.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for your comment. Since audio format and encoding is a little bit unity specific it's hard to make a console app to test that but you gave me an idea. console.dialogflow.com has a handy test tool and I can even copy the curl command. So I'll do that but pass the audio encoded from unity instead of whatever in the console. I'm worried about the huge length of the curl command but I'll try to make it work for testing.

Comment: The audio format really shouldn't be Unity-specific - you'll need to use an audio format/encoding that Dialogflow supports, after all. Just record a file using Audacity or something similar, and you can try that from a console app. Again, this is all part of the diagnostic process - if you can get it working in a simple environment, that suggests the problem is what you're doing in Unity, not the Dialogflow API. You should be aiming to isolate the problem as far as you can.

Comment: Or if you can get the data from Unity, you can use *that* from a console app - that would be clearer than using curl, IMO. Fundamentally the approach is the same though: as Unity is an unsupported platform, take it out of the picture to start with.

Comment: @JonSkeet Just added an edit with the example console app. Thank you for advance.

Comment: Okay, and *is* the audio Linear16, with the sample rate you're specifying? Additionally, is it mono or stereo? (I know with the Speech API, you need to provide mono audio.) Do you have a sample file that you know *is* valid? (I assume your session name is actually correct, not the one you've provided there?)

Comment: @JonSkeet I specified the sample rate for unity so it should generate the audio with that sample rate. Regarding Linear16 I'm not sure but I thought that because previous API.AI V1 unity sample assumed unity audio source to be linear 16. I also checked that the generated audio channels are only 1. Regarding session it's actually the one specified in the code (the project id is a placeholder however). sometimes I entered sessions/session1 or something, is that wrong?

Comment: Okay, so again I would try to take any unknowns out of the problem for the moment: try a definitely-correct audio file. If that works but your audio file doesn't, then it's the audio file that's the problem. I've just tried it with a mono WAV file exported straight from Audacity (using 44100 as the sample frequency, as that's the default) and it was fine. That was detecting English - which again, I'd probably use for the test, to simplify things.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. It works now, but the whole things is too complicated for Unity. I hope to see official support for unity for Grpc (out of beta) and dialog flow V2. Game creators will definitely want to use that kind of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer. The way I converted the datasource float to linear16 byte array was obviously wrong. Here's the code that worked
Credits to that post on unity forum.

> https://forum.unity.com/threads/writing-audiolistener-getoutputdata-to-wav-problem.119295/#post-899142

```
public static byte[] convertToBytes(float[] dataSource)
{
    var intData = new Int16[dataSource.Length];
    //converting in 2 steps : float[] to Int16[], //then Int16[] to Byte[]

    var bytesData = new Byte[dataSource.Length * 2];
    //bytesData array is twice the size of
    //dataSource array because a float converted in Int16 is 2 bytes.

    var rescaleFactor = 32767; //to convert float to Int16

    for (var i = 0; i < dataSource.Length; i++)
    {
        intData[i] = (short)(dataSource[i] * rescaleFactor);
        var byteArr = new byte[2];
        byteArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(intData[i]);
        byteArr.CopyTo(bytesData, i * 2);
    }

    return bytesData;
}
```

Comment: DialogFlow returns an "empty" JSON in response to a silent utterance or random noise. It is not ideal. You can do nothing but handle that somehow in your application.